# pygameのエラー: SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character

Tags: python, python3

```
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
```

これはどういうエラーですか？

Comment: 実際にエラーが発生するコードをお見せいただけますか？

Comment: 参考: [You can't put anything after the line continuation character `\\`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36657850)

Answer (score -1):

とりあえずgoogle翻訳
SyntaxError: 行継続文字の後の予期しない文字

あるあるなのが全角文字が混じってたとか、全角空白がはいってたとか。